# Webpage menus not quite right

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty figuring out why my menus are on top of each other instead of side by side.  See image:

[image]

Can someone please explain what I need to do to have them appear side by side?

My HTML looks like this:

```
<nav id="top_menu">
  <img src="media/images/logo_large.jpg">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">
      <a href="#">Nav Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li>
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">       
      <a href="#">Nav Item 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

My CSS looks like so:

```
#top_menu{
 position: relative;
 top:35px;
 left: 90px;
 width:660px;
 height:55px;
 background-color: black;
 border:1px solid white;
 opacity:0.6;
 filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.dropdown {
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
float: right;
padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.dropdown a {
background: black repeat-x;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
color: white;
display: block;
line-height: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
height: 25px;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
color: #30B3FF;
background: #666;
}

.dropdown ul a {
background: black;
}

.dropdown li {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font: bold 12px Tahoma; 
width: 120px;
}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
}

.dropdown ul {
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 26px;
left: -1px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown ul {
display: none;
}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want them side-by-side, then you'll want to use **either** `float` or `display:inline-block`:

If you don't mind them stacking to the left, and dealing with how floats need to be handled, then this will work:

```
.dropdown > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 12px Tahoma; 
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
```

Notice the `>` direct descendant selector: `.dropdown > li` - this applies this style only to your top-level li elements.  This will save you time and effort when it comes to styling your drop-downs.

If you want to allow them to variable width, or you don't want them stacked left:

```
.dropdown > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold 12px Tahoma; 
    display: inline-block;
    /* IE7 hack to make inline-block work right */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Well, this solved part of my problems.  Please see my additional post above.