# Why do menu bullets show up on my menus?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create menus for a webpage using HTML and CSS. When the menus are displayed those nasty bullets appear.  I don't want them.  How do I get rid of them?

Also, the submenus need to allow for variable length strings.  I had to specify a `width: 80px;` property for the `.dropdown li` element.  If I didn't, all the menus got squished together.

For the submenus, if I have a lengthy li like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Most Popular Artists</a></li>
```

All that gets displayed is the word "Most".

So I need two things solved: Get rid of the bullets, and make the submenus handle variable length strings.

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav id="top_menu">
<img src="media/images/logo_large.jpg">
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">
      <a href="#">NEWS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li>
    <li class="dropdown_trigger">       
      <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem1</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem2</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem3</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#">Subitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#top_menu{
 position: relative;
 top:35px;
 left: 90px;
 width:660px;
 height:55px;
 background-color: black;
 border:1px solid black;
 opacity:0.6;
 filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
.dropdown {
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
float: right;
padding: 1px 0 0 1px;
margin: 0 0 20px;
line-height: 55px;
}

.dropdown a {
background: black repeat-x;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
color: white;
display: block;
line-height: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
height: 25px;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
color: #30B3FF;
background: #666;
}

.dropdown ul a {
background: black;
}

.dropdown > li {
list-style: none;
position: relative;
text-align: left;
font: bold 12px Tahoma; 
*display: inline-block;
width: 80px;
/* IE7 hack to make inline-block work right */
*zoom: 1;
display: inline;

}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger {

display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
}

.dropdown ul {
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 26px;
left: -1px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown ul {
display: none;
}

.dropdown li.dropdown_trigger:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZg4V/) but I didn't found any so called `nasty bullets`

Comment: It could be a caching issue. It works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VpwYx/)

Comment: @JakeGould How would I know that? Oh, if you edit your answer in some way I'll be able to remove my downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `list-style-type: none;` to your main `ul` CSS like so:

```
.dropdown ul {
list-style-type: none;
background: black;
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-width: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 26px;
left: -1px;
z-index: 9999;
}

.dropdown ul {
display: none;
}
```

And looking at that you can consolidate those two items & format them for readability as well:

```
.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

And past that you can even add the `!important` to force an override:

```
.dropdown ul {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none !important;
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  left: -1px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Ah, but it was it.  That cured the bullet problem on my end.  Now, I just have the issue with the submenus. How do I get lengthy strings to appear and not be restricted by the width:80px; property defined in .dropdown > li {} ?

Comment: @Alan - you use the answer I suggested in your earlier question - use `display: inline-block`, and don't set a width (let them stretch automatically): http://stackoverflow.com/a/23458542/870729

Answer (score 0):

Add `list-style:none;` to your [unordered (bulleted)](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) list to hide the default bullets. Apply this role to `ul` in this way you will not have to apply it to each `ul.class` every time.

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```